# Nouveau problem freeze

Tags: debian, nouveau

I want to know, why I can't use Nouveau driver.

I explain:

When I use on my MSI GP62 6QF 1016 laptop computer my Nouveau driver, my Debian freezes with this error:

```
nouveau pci: failed to adjust inkctl speed.
```

And if I blacklist Nouveau, my Debian works fine.

But I want to know why when I used my nouveau driver, my computer freezes.

Comment: This is probably a question to the developers of the Noveau driver.  Moreover, you will need to give **a lot** of hardware details for it to be possible to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot distribution exsting with newer than actuel debian 8.6 with better implementation or your hardware.

So pick one distribution popular is tried it.
Personally, i tried fedora which was better hardware implementation than debian.
But the best was LinuxMint i can easily install nvidia-driver without any problem and all laptop functionality work very well.